# infinite update loop in a component render function Vuejs

Tags: vue.js

when I try to push selected data to an array It shows

> infinite update loop in a component render function.

error. I tried similar answers but didn't work.

```
                    <v-select v-for="(orderCategory, k) in orderCategories"
                              :items="orderCategory.items"
                              :label="orderCategory.name"
                              v-model="selectedCatAddon[orderCategory.id]"
                              @change="selectCatOption(orderCategory,selectedCatAddon[orderCategory.id])"
                              item-text="name"
                              return-object
                              :key="'B'+k"

                    > </v-select>
```

Script Part...

```
selectCatOption(selectedorderCategory, selectedAddon) {

            if (selectedorderCategory && selectedAddon) {
                let model = {
                    'id': selectedAddon.id,
                    'name': selectedAddon.name,
                    'category': selectedorderCategory,
                    'primary': selectedAddon.primary,
                    'loyalty_price': selectedAddon.loyalty_price,
                    'price_type': selectedAddon.price_type,
                    'price': selectedAddon.price,
                    'discount': selectedAddon.discount,
                    'discount_special': selectedAddon.special_discount,
                };


                let found = this.selectedFeatureArray.find(product => product.category === model.category);
                console.log(found);
                if (found) {
                    let deleting = this.selectedFeatureArray.findIndex(product => product.id === model.id);
                    this.selectedFeatureArray.splice(deleting, 1);
                }
                this.selectedFeatureArray.push(model);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you provide a codesandbox  with minimal code?

Comment: Does your console logging log multiple times? I don't see an obvious cause within the code provided, my guess would be that the problem lies within a section of the template that uses `selectedFeatureArray` or a computed property derived from it. The error suggests that you are changing some reactive data during rendering, causing it to re-render over and over.

Comment: This error message usually means that one of the variables referenced in your template has a side-effect, which causes one of the variables referenced in your template to be changed. This change causes a re-render, starting this process again. You do not currently provide enough code to reproduce the problem, which makes it impossible for us to tell you exactly what is going on.

Comment: I figured out the problem. An computed property caused the error. Sorry if I wasted your time. Thanx all 